# Decorating a class method with a class method

Tags: python, decorator

I was decorating a class method with another class method. The class looks like this

```
from functools import wraps

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Within my class object')

    def my_decorator(func_to_decorate):
        @wraps(func_to_decorate)
        def wrapper(self):
            print('Before the call')

            func_to_decorate(self)

            print('After the function call')
        return wrapper

    @my_decorator
    def print_name(self):
        print('My name is ------ ')

mobj = MyClass()
mobj.print_name()
```

Works fine I get the output that I need

```
Before the call
My name is ------ 
After the function call
```

But then while looking at the function definition of the decorator `my_decorator` I realised that the method did not take what a class method usually takes as its first argument `self`

My question now is - What is the type of `my_decorator`? Is it a class method, normal method or a special method?

Normally methods within a class take the implicit argument `self` or if its a class method take the implicit argument `cls`. The decorator is taking neither of them.

Can some one please explain what is happening here?

Comment: As a side note, you are confusing class methods with instance methods.  Regular methods are called instance methods, since they take an instance as their first argument `self`.  Class methods are created using the decorator `@classmethod` and take a class as their first argument, usually called `cls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple function as you're not accessing it from a class or an instance, so `self` or `cls` is not required for that function when used inside the class definition as a decorator. The implicit arguments are forced by such functions only when we access them with either class or instance, because accessing them through class or instance returns unbound and bound methods which are thin wrappers around the original function.

If you move the decorator outside of the class then you'll see that it expects you to send an instance as first argument:

```
MyClass.print_name = MyClass.my_decorator(MyClass.print_name)
mobj = MyClass()
mobj.print_name()
```

**Error:**

```
MyClass.print_name = MyClass.my_decorator(MyClass.print_name)
TypeError: unbound method my_decorator() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got instancemethod instance instead)
```

Though you can prevent this error by declaring `my_decorator` as a staticmethod which expects neither `self` or `cls` or access the underlying function using the `im_func` attribute of bound, unbound objects:

```
MyClass.print_name = MyClass.my_decorator.im_func(MyClass.print_name)
```

You should read the **Callable types** part on [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) page.